# Problem with NMOS simulation in OrCAD

Tags: nmos, pspice, orcad

I have to run a simulation on how NMOS transistors work using OrCAD PSpice.

Schematic:
[image]

Simulation Profile:

[image]

Simulation:

[image]

As you can see the problem is that after sweeping VGS from 0 V to 12 V the simulation shows that the current of VDS is 0, which is wrong.
Any solutions?

Comment: Perhaps the model isn't working or isn't linked properly (requires an .include (.inc) card). Try using a part in the PSpice library and see if the simulation gives better results.